# Subsonic use All() or Find()?

Tags: subsonic

What is better?

Use:

GridView.DataSource = ObjectFromDB.All().Where(a => a.ID == null);

Or:

GridView.DataSource = ObjectFromDB.Find(a => a.ID == null);

?

Comment: Good question. I'm new to SubSonic 3.0 I'm coming from 2.0